# MVC 3 How to uploade images and save filename to db

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a **Portfolio Item** in my model and the **Create view** for it has **4 fields** for image file names. How can I add a button to each field, so I can upload an image to a folder and then add the file name to the html input control.

I guessing **jQuery** would be the way to go, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Also I found this [MVC image upload with filename stored in db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984243/mvc-image-upload-with-filename-stored-in-db) about saving the uploading the image and saving the file name to the database, but my administration site is on a sub-domain, and the main web site is in a different directory. Would I still be able to upload the image to the Content/Images folder of my main site?

#### My site directory is as follows

- Frontend - This is the main site
- Backend  - This is the admin site

To clarify I need to be able to upload the image to the Frontend/Content/Images directory, from the site in the Backend application directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your view you have to enctype  e.g.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Name", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Then add an upload input to your HTML or you can use the MVC HTML helpers for this  e.g.

```
  <input type="file" id="LogoData" name="LogoData" />
```

Then in your controller

```
     public ActionResult Edit(YourEditModel, HttpPostedFileBase LogoData)
            {
                byte[] imgBinaryData = null;
                    if (LogoData != null && LogoData.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        imgBinaryData = new byte[LogoData.ContentLength];
                        int readresult = LogoData.InputStream.Read(imgBinaryData, 0, LogoData.ContentLength);
                        // use File.IO to save to your disk. you can use server mappath to get current foldername
                    }
}
```

Get it first working for 1 file,  Then worry about trying to upload 4 files.